# Give Result to the same Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a Activity i use to get a folderpath. To Navigate to the next folder i create a intent to this Activity with the path of the folder. When i try to return the result it gets lost in the middle.

Giving the result:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_ok:
                returnIntent.putExtra("path", filename);
                Log.d("Result", "Picker"+String.valueOf(RESULT_OK));
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_abort:
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
                finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Navigation (Yes, it's a ListActivity):

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        filename = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        if (path.endsWith(File.separator))
        {
            filename = path + filename;
        }
        else
        {
            filename = path + File.separator + filename;
        }
        if (new File(filename).isDirectory())
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DirectoryPicker.class);
            intent.putExtra("path", filename);
            startActivityForResult(intent,0);
        } 
        this.finish();
    }
```

Getting the result:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (getIntent() != null)
        {
            Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> When i try to return the result it gets lost in the middle.

It is not lost in the middle. You are looking for the result in the wrong place. `getIntent()` returns the intent through with your `Activity` was started. It has not knowledge of the result you set in the other `Activity`. You have to use the third parameter of `onActivityResult`, `Intent data`.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (data != null) {
       setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
       finish();
   }
```